# Can't upgrade packages in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, kernel

I recently upgraded my linux kernel version. The command `$ uname -r` shows the following output -

`5.17.5-051705-generic`

But whenever I try to upgrade any package or simply run `$ sudo apt-get upgrade`, it throws an error as shows below -

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: The package linux-headers-5.17.5-051705 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

Same error is shows when I try to purge this kernel image.

Comment: How did you upgrade the kernel? AFAIK, you're not using a supported kernel.

Comment: I had referred to this article while upgrading kernel - https://nextgentips.com/2022/03/21/how-to-upgrade-linux-kernel-to-5-17-release-on-ubuntu-20-04/

Comment: Is there a good reason why you did this? Mainline kernels are for testing. They are not appropriate for production or general use and have no support. See: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds

Comment: Is there a way I can revert back to previous version? I tried advanced options with Ubuntu to make changes but it didn't help.

Comment: Unless you uninstalled the original kernel, you can reboot and choose to boot the old kernel from the GRUB menu. Then you can uninstall the newer one.